# Parsing NLP con lista externa

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsear, nlp

Teniendo un texto de entrada que pasará por la gramática y la salida debe ser todas las entradas que la gramática encuentra en el texto. El problema es que mis no terminales son archivos de listas externas y no encuentro una manera de hacerlo.

**Ejemplo de un pseudo-cógigo:**

1. Abrir un texto
2. Pasar la gramática (sólo un ejemplo):

   ```
   grammar ("""    
   S -> NP VP    
   NP -> DET N    
   VP -> V N    
   DET -> **lista_det.txt**    
   N -> **lista_n.txt**
   V -> **lista.txt** """)
   ```
3. Impresión de los resultados del texto que obedecen a la gramática

**Ejemplo:**

```
with open ("corpus_risque.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read()

    grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""
    S-> NP VP
    NP -> DET N
    VP -> V N 
    DET -> lista_det.txt
    N -> lista_n.txt
    V -> lista.txt""")

    parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)
    parsed = parser.parse(texte)
    print(texte)
```

Normalmente, las gramáticas se presentan de esta forma, ya en listas:

```
grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""

S -> NP VP
VP -> VBZ NP PP
PP -> IN NP
NP -> NNP | DT JJ NN NN | NN
NNP -> 'Python'
VBZ -> 'is'
DT -> 'a'
JJ -> 'good'
NN -> 'programming' | 'language' | 'research'
IN -> 'for'
""")
```

¿Sería posible hacer lo que pretendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no comprendí mal el problema, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente: Supongamos que tienes un archivo `lista_det.txt` de la siguiente forma:

```
el
la
un | una
```

Lo podemos leer linea a linea y concatenarlo a una variable, por ejemplo:

```
gramatica ="""
S-> NP VP
NP -> DET N
VP -> V N 
"""

with open("lista_det.txt", "r") as f:
  gramatica = gramatica + "".join(["DET -> {0}".format(line) for line in f])

print(gramatica)
```

Básicamente recorremos todas las líneas del archivo `lista_det.txt` y las concatenamos a la variable `gramatica` anteponiendoles el texto `DET ->`, todo terminaría generando algo así:

```
S-> NP VP
NP -> DET N
VP -> V N 
DET -> el
DET -> la
DET -> un | una
```

Repetimos el procedimiento para las listas de sustantivos y de verbos y luego simplemente cargamos la gramática directamente da la variable `gramatica` que hemos ido llenado:

```
grammar = nltk.parse_cfg(gramatica)
```

Comment: Sé que no se puede agradecer, pero tengo que hacer eso ... muy agradecida!!